# Create a index list of weeks and inside at each list have a list of Hours in Flutter

Tags: flutter

this is a picture of what I did in static form:

[image]

the code to achieve what I did is:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 7,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 117,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      WeekDays.days[index],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 250,
                  width: 117,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: ReservationTime.hours.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 50,
                                    width: 117,
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                      },
                                      child: new Card(
                                        elevation: 10,
                                        child: Center(child: Text(ReservationTime.hours[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.white))),
                                    ),
                                  ),),
                                ]
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

the 2 list where I grab the data are for Horizontal Week Days is:

```
class WeekDays {
  static final List<String> days = ['Monday 07 Dic', 'Tuesday 08 Dic', 'Wednesday 09 Dic', 'Thursday 10 Dic', 'Friday 11 Dic', 'Saturday 12 Dic', 'Sunday 13 Dic'];
}
```

and for vertical List is:

```
class ReservationTime {
  static final List<String> hours = ['00.00 - 00.20', '00.20 - 00-40', '00.40 - 01.00', '01.00 - 01.20', '01.20 - 01.40','01.40 - 02.00','02.00 - 02.20','02.20 - 02.40','02.40 - 03.00','03.00 - 03.20','03.20 - 03.40','03.40 - 04.00','04.00 - 04.20','04.20 - 04.40','04.40 - 05.00'];
}
```

what I want to do as per picture ,is with the Button marked by the Red Arrow switch the Week list to the next week and with other arrow to the last week.
Of course I need to get the current day of the week and an Index of all the weeks of the year.
I know that my method is some wrong but I am here to ask if someone has an idea how to achieve that.
I need to create a calendar with possibility to the user to booking the time by clicking on each element then this element will change color and send his state to the database.

Comment: selection will be single or multiple ?

Comment: the selection of each Item of the vertical list is single.
The most important things is horizontal weekly list index

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to scroll freely horizontally? Or should it always snap, so that Monday settles into the left-most position?

Comment: Horizontaly the user should change the weekly view so he can freely click on the button above > to go to the next week and < to the last week
obivosuly the content of the list should be according of the week data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in a PageView.builder and feed it a PageController

```
PageView.builder(
    controller: _pageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, weekIndex) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 7,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        int milliseconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch - (now.weekday - 1)*24*60*60*1000 + weekIndex*7*24*60*60*1000 + index*24*60*60*1000;
        DateTime dayDateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
        int monthIndex = dayDateTime.month - 1;
        List months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        List weekdays = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
        String month = months[monthIndex];
        String day = dayDateTime.day.toString();
        String weekday = weekdays[dayDateTime.weekday - 1];
        String date = weekday + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
        return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Column(children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 117,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  date,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                )),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 250,
                width: 117,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: ReservationTime.hours.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Column(children: [
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 117,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: new Card(
                                    elevation: 10,
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                            ReservationTime.hours[index],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                color: Colors.white))),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ))
          ])
        ]);
      });})
```

Outside your build you want to initialise your PageController via

```
PageController _pageController = PageController();
```

Now to get a button to go to nextPage use the PageController method:

```
_pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.ease)
```

and similarly to go back:

```
_pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), curve: Curves.ease)
```

The block within the first ListView.builder shows how you can assign the correct date to each day, there are probably more elegant ways of doing this...

Comment: Ok great but how to get the week index according with the real week for example today.. 11 dic.. and so one.. ?

Comment: See the edit I've just made on how to set the date. Is this what you needed?

Comment: sorry I placed the code in the wrong place it works perfectly! 100%

Comment: I have just a question how to indentify current day variable to give another color to the item with the day current?

Comment: Within the ListView builder, if you call `now.weekday` it returns an int value 1->7 (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday), so `now.weekday == index + 1` (because index goes from 0 -> 6) is true if the weekday is todays weekday (Saturday). However this is true for ALL saturdays, so you want to use `now.weekday == index + 1 && weekIndex == 0` which ensures it's not true for future Saturdays.

Comment: Hello can I ask you how to have the MonthIndex to use into Pageview.builder to scroll per month and not per week? because now is set up weekIndex and it scroll each week I need now month

Comment: The method works by getting the current day and time represented by "milliseconds since epoch", then subtracting N days worth of milliseconds to get the Monday of the current week, this is what `now.millisecondsSinceEpoch - (now.weekday - 1)*24*60*60*1000` is doing. Previously, I added two extra terms to shift the milliseconds by weeks (weekIndex*7*24*60*60*1000) and days (index*24*60*60*1000). To shift by a month you need a term like monthIndex*30*7*24*60*60*1000, where would need to relabel weekIndex -> monthIndex.